# Problem with Text field parsing to get data in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, text-parsing

I receives data in this format.

`var data="frame=  159 fps= 51 q=34.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:05.37 bitrate= 780.3kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=1.72x";`

To use the delimiter here the only possibility is space.
But for that `frame=   159` which has more spaces after = creating the problem.
Same problem with frame, size, bitrate.

So I can't use either delimiter or simple string split i.e `data.Split(" ")`

How to parse values here to correct DTO/Object.

```
public class Template
{
   public float Frame {get;set;}
   public float Fps {get;set;}
   public string Size {get;set;}
   public TimeSpan Time {get;set;}
   public string Bitrate {get;set;}
   public short Dup {get;set;}
   public short Drop {get;set;}
   public string Speed {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: well, you know the spaces separating the entries _aren't preceeded by an equal sign_. so you could just remove all spaces that _are_. alternatively: this seems easy enough to solve with a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove spaces after `=` using Regex

```
var data = "frame=  159 fps= 51 q=34.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:05.37 bitrate= 780.3kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=1.72x";
data = Regex.Replace(data, @"=\s+", "=");
foreach (var d in data.Split(' '))
{
    var kv = d.Split('=');
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", kv[0], kv[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your `string` to `<key,value>` collection by remove unnecessary spaces:

```
var data="frame=  159 fps= 51 q=34.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:05.37 bitrate= 780.3kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=1.72x".Replace("  ", " ");
data = Regex.Replace(data, @"[^\S]+", " ");
data = Regex.Replace(data, @"= ", "=");
var pairs = data.Split(" ");
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    var keyAndValue = pair.Split("=");
    if (keyAndValue.Length == 2)
    {
        dictionary.Add(keyAndValue[0], keyAndValue[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```